# How to infer subtype of generic in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function with some argument's type:

```js
function func<T extends {field1: string}>(arg1: T) {
 // function's code
}
```

I have a familiar interface with generic type, like this:

```
interface SomeInterface<T> {
    field1: string;
}
```

Now i want to infer generic parameter of interface and assign it to function's return type:

```
const value1: SomeInterface<number> = {field1: "Hello"};

const res1 = func(value1);
```

I need a type for *res1* is **number**.

What a function's signature i need to use?

```
function func<T extends {field1: string}>(arg1: T) : T extends ???? { // What?
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in using a generic type in an interface if the type is not being referenced by any attribute.

Here is an interface which receives a generic type and applies that type to one of its attributes:

```
interface SomeInterface<T> {
    field1: T;
}
```

In other hand, if you want to create function with a generic return type:

```
function func<T>(): T {
 // code
}

// function call
const res1 = func<number>();
```

And finally, if you want your function to receive as argument a generic type and return another generic type:

```
function func<T, R>(arg: T) : R {
 // code
}

// function call
const res1 = func<SomeInterface, number>(value1);
```

Comment: Sorry, but there is point for this.  For example: 

`interface SomeInterface<_T>{
  field1: string;
}

function func1<T>(arg: T): T extends SomeInterface<infer R> ? R : never {
}
const value1: SomeInterface<number> = {field1: "hello"};
const res1 = func1(value1); // res1 has type a number`

Comment: @Alisa [see this FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--).  If a generic type `G<T>` doesn't use its type parameter `T` in its structure, then you can't expect the compiler to keep track of it.